Necessary conditions on a pdf $f(x)$ with positive support for its Laplace transform $\hat f(s)$ to go to zero as $s\to\infty$
Let $f(x)$ be a probability density function with positive support, i.e. $x>0$, $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=1$ and $f(x)\geq 0$.
Let $\hat f(s)=\int_0^\infty dx~f(x)e^{-sx}$ be its Laplace transform.
What are necessary conditions on $f(x)$ to have $\lim_{s\to\infty}\hat{f}(s)=0$ ?

No additional assumptions are needed, it seems.
